# How does basic HTTP Auth work?

Tags: authentication, http

How does basic HTTP Auth work?

Comment: Explained very well on the wikipedia page unless there is something you don't understand - http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basic_access_authentication

Comment: @Ams - Implementations and mechanisms are very related to security, as they can be used in researching exploits. I asked this specifically because of a comment on this answer: http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/730/is-it-possible-to-change-the-admin-user-password-remotely-on-a-router-without-log/735#735

Comment: @Moshe, I think SE IT security is more about practical approach, rather than something that requires reading RFC, tech notes and manuals. Similarly to this question, we can generate a lot of others questions regarding "how stuff works" - e.g. "how SOP is implemented", "how web-server works". At some point they are also related to security. But IMO, these are those questions that are not reasonable to ask community - something that is possible to get easy on your own or through little research.

Comment: @makerofthings the stackexchange team disagrees with you: http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/07/area-51-asking-the-first-questions/

Comment: Thanks Gram for showing me a new perspective; I just removed my comment above.

Comment: Here I have written blog post on "[How HTTP authentication works?](https://medium.com/@bitshadow/how-basic-http-authentication-and-session-works-d29af9caec31)". Hope it will clear your doubts.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

The server sends back a header stating it requires authentication for a given realm. The user provides the username and password, which the browser concatenates (username + ":" + password), and base64 encodes. This encoded string is then sent using a "Authorization"-header on each request from the browser.
Because the credentials are only encoded, not encrypted, this is highly insecure unless it is sent over https.

Answer (score 1):

The server sends a request to the user for the authentication for the site, the user provides the username and password, the browser rearranges it to be (username + ":" + password), and encodes it, the encoded password is then sent to the server and lets you in if correct